# Mongoose.js: Atomic update of nested properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using Mongoose version 3.6.4

Say I have a MongoDB document like so:

```
{
    "_id" : "5187b74e66ee9af96c39d3d6",
    "profile" : {
        "name" : {
            "first" : "Joe",
            "last" : "Pesci",
            "middle" : "Frank"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following schema for Users:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id:    { type: String },
  email:  { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
  active: { type: Boolean, required: true, 'default': false },
  profile: {
    name: {
      first:    { type: String, required: true },
      last:     { type: String, required: true },
      middle:   { type: String }
    }
  }
  created:    { type: Date, required: true, 'default': Date.now},
  updated:    { type: Date, required: true, 'default': Date.now}
);
```

And I submit a form passing a field named: `profile[name][first]` with a value of `Joseph`

and thus I want to update just the user's first name, but leave his last and middle alone, I thought I would just do:

```
User.update({email: "joe@foo.com"}, req.body, function(err, result){});
```

But when I do that, it "deletes" the `profile.name.last` and `profile.name.middle` properties and I end up with a doc that looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "5187b74e66ee9af96c39d3d6",
    "profile" : {
        "name" : {
            "first" : "Joseph"
        }
    }
}
```

So it's basically overwriting all of `profile` with `req.body.profile`, which I guess makes sense. Is there any way around it without having to be more explicit by specifying my fields in the update query instead of `req.body`?

Comment: Consider accepting Aichholzer's answer as it provides a real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are correct, Mongoose converts updates to `$set` for you. But this doesn't solve your issue. Try it out in the mongodb shell and you'll see the same behavior.

Instead, to update a single deeply nested property you need to specify the full path to the deep property in the `$set`.

```
User.update({ email: 'joe@foo.com' }, { 'profile.name.first': 'Joseph' }, callback)
```

Comment: Right, but I was hoping I could just pass in `req.body` so I didn't have to specify all the possible fields. So I ended up doing a `findById()` first, deleting `__v` and `_id` from the found doc, using `_.deepExtend()` to merge in the new updated properties, and then passing my frankenstein object to Mongoose's `update`.

Comment: @aaronheckmann, is there anyway telling mongoose or mongo that "here is my latest object, simply just update it"?

Comment: @k00k - Is that approach atomic? Won't it still write the entire doc again? Why do you have to remove __v and _id?

Comment: @DouglasFerguson It's been a long time since this specific issue and version of Mongoose, so I'll try to remember,  but Mongoose update is atomic by default. See aaronheckman's answer regarding $set. As for the __v and __id, not sure why I was doing that, seems not needed now, but I'm sure there was a reason with the way I was doing the deepExtend. Sorry, I can't recall on that bit.

Comment: How about an edit to show the example using flattening library, like https://github.com/hughsk/flat - so there's no need to "translate" nested paths manually?

Answer (score 12):

One very easy way to solve this with `Moongose 4.1` and the `flat` package:

```
var flat = require('flat'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        schema = new Schema(
            {
                name: {
                    first: {
                        type: String,
                        trim: true
                    },
                    last: {
                        type: String,
                        trim: true
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function () {
        this._update = flat(this._update);
    });


    mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

`req.body` (for example) can now be:

```
{
    name: {
        first: 'updatedFirstName'
    }
}
```

The object will be flattened before the actual query is executed, thus `$set` will update only the expected properties instead of the entire `name` object.

Comment: just be careful when having nested ObjectId's. flat will turn those into 'something._bsontype': 'ObjectID', 'something.id': <Buffer 58 36 ..>'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for $set

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/

```
User.update({email: "joe@foo.com"}, { $set : req.body}, function(err, result){});
```

Try that

Comment: I thought that Mongoose was "safe" by default and so an `update` really is a `$set`, am I wrong?

Comment: And to add, I just tried it and it doesn't work. It seems to be a problem with the nested properties. Just to clarify, it's only the nested properties at the same level (siblings) that get blown away.

Comment: you are looking for $set with a specific field name - "name.first".  This has nothing to do with safe vs unsafe writes, just whether you are telling it to update the entire document or a single field.

Comment: @all, I have been trying to find my answer and hope someone would know. Is there anyway telling mongoose or mongo that "here is my latest object, simply just update it"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good solution - add option to Model.update, that replace nested objects like:

{field1: 1, fields2: {a: 1, b:2 }} => {'field1': 1, 'field2.a': 1, 'field2.b': 2}

```
  nestedToDotNotation: function(obj, keyPrefix) {
    var result;
    if (keyPrefix == null) {
      keyPrefix = '';
    }
    result = {};
    _.each(obj, function(value, key) {
      var nestedObj, result_key;
      result_key = keyPrefix + key;
      if (!_.isArray(value) && _.isObject(value)) {
        result_key += '.';
        nestedObj = module.exports.nestedToDotNotation(value, result_key);
        return _.extend(result, nestedObj);
      } else {
        return result[result_key] = value;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

});

need improvements circular reference handling, but this is really useful when working with nested objects

I'm using underscore.js here, but these functions easily can be replaced with other analogs